# C++ Are there different types of alarms?

Tags: c++

Apart from the standard \a, are there any other alarm commands that are of different notes? Is there a specific library that contains this function?

Comment: The standard says that `\a` is "intended" to "produce an audible tone or visible alert" when sent to a display device, but provides no other requirements. The standard does not provide for any customization of the tone, or even any guarantee that a tone is produced at all.

Answer (score 4):

When sent to some terminal programs, `\a` indeed plays an audible note.  Some terminals allow that to be disabled, or e.g. changed to flash the screen.  It only tends to work in non-GUI text-mode terminals.  There are no other such codes that are anywhere near as common across terminals, though you could check the documentation for your particular terminal program.

More generally, you'll have to look for some system specific mechanism to play notes, as the C++ language and Standard Library do not provide any such facilities.